# Java JPA @OneToMany needed to reciprocate @ManyToOne?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, persistence

```
Create Table A (
ID varchar(8),
Primary Key(ID)
);

Create Table B (
ID varchar(8),
A_ID varchar(8),
Primary Key(ID),
Foreign Key(A_ID) References A(ID)
);
```

Given that I have created two tables using the SQL statements above, and I want to create `Entity` classes for them, for the class `B`, I have these member attributes:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 8)
private String id;
@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private A AId;
```

In class `A`, do I need to reciprocate the many-to-one relationship?

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 8)
private String id;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "AId")
private List<B> BList; //<-- Is this attribute necessary?
```

Is it a necessary or a good idea to have a reciprocal `@OneToMany` for the `@ManyToOne`? If I make the design decision to leave out the `@OneToMany` annotated attribute now, would that come back to bite me further along?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it a necessary or a good idea to have a reciprocal @OneToMany  for the @ManyToOne?

No, it's not mandatory at all, it's a pure design decision. The whole question is... Do you want this (i.e. an uni-directional association):

[image: uni-directional]

Or this (i.e. a bi-directional association):

[image: bi-directional]

If you don't need to get Bs from A, then you can skip the `bs` attribute and the `OneToMany` on A side.

> If I make the design decision to leave out the @OneToMany annotated attribute now, will come back to bite me further down.

No, and you can add it later if you discover that you need it.

Comment: +1 and check @Pascal Thivent : For pointing out I can add it later if I need it: that was my main concern.

Comment: I usually try to avoid unidirectional mappings as much as possible. Just because something in the datebase is modeled with a separate join table (for whatever reason) doesnt mean my object-model has to do the same. In the example above, an OneToOne-Mapping would be sufficient for the uni-directional solution (of course this must adhere to the domain).

Comment: This is quite clear and confident. I had this doubt for a while but now everything makes sense.

Comment: @OneToMany can still be beneficial, even if you don't need it. With the `cascade` attribute you can automatically have the child entities (on the @ManyToOne side) removed when deleting the parent entity

Answer (score 2):

They are optional. There is no need to add them to your model if you don't want to use them.

I'd sugguest to avoid the reverse mapping at all because such collections may become quite large and most persistance layers don't handle these very good. In many cases you'd have to deal with add/remove of already loaded/managed entities related to these collections yourself. So only add those if they really make things easier for you.

Comment: +1 @Daniel Bleisteiner : The sheer amount of code needed to handle them can get quite unwieldy. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Sure not. Thats design decision between one vs two direction relationship. In most casses, a better choice is to have one direction relationship, especially if its a domain classes. doing this, your design will express better the mean of your domain.